# lm() called within mutate()

Tags: r, lm, dplyr

I wonder if it is possible to use lm() within mutate() of dplyr package. Currently I have a dataframe of "date", "company", "return" and "market.ret" reproducible as below:

```
library(dplyr)
n.dates <- 60
n.stocks <- 2
date <- seq(as.Date("2011-07-01"), by=1, len=n.dates)
symbol <- replicate(n.stocks, paste0(sample(LETTERS, 5), collapse = ""))
x <- expand.grid(date, symbol)
x$return <- rnorm(n.dates*n.stocks, 0, sd = 0.05)
names(x) <- c("date", "company", "return")
x <- group_by(x, date)    
x <- mutate(x, market.ret = mean(x$return, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Now for each company I would like to fit "return" by "market.ret", calculate the linear regression coefficient and store the slopes in a new column. I wish to do it with mutate(), but the below code does not work:

```
x <- group_by(x, company)
x <- mutate(x, beta = coef(lm(x$return~x$market.ret))[[2]])
```

The error reported by R is:

```
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
invalid term in model formula
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
group_by(x, company) %>%
    do(data.frame(beta = coef(lm(return ~ market.ret,data = .))[2])) %>%
    left_join(x,.)
```

Comment: I'd probably use `do()` to create the model then extract the coefficients in a separate step.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to calculate a daily market return across all companies, and then regress return vs. market return for each company, across all days. If so, here's a solution using `data.table`; likely to be faster with very large datasets.

```
library(data.table) ## 1.9.2+
setDT(x)[ , market.ret := mean(return), by = date]
x[, beta := coef(lm(return ~ market.ret, data = .SD))[[2]], by = company]
```

---

where `x` is as shown below (using `set.seed` for reproducibility):

```
set.seed(1L)     # for reproducible example
n.dates <- 60
n.stocks <- 2
date <- seq(as.Date("2011-07-01"), by=1, len=n.dates)
symbol <- replicate(n.stocks, paste0(sample(LETTERS, 5), collapse = ""))
x <- expand.grid(date, symbol)
x$return <- rnorm(n.dates*n.stocks, 0, sd = 0.05)
names(x) <- c("date", "company", "return")
```

Comment: @Arun The reason I put the code in one block (rather than two blocks in reverse order as you did in your edit) is so that OP can cut/paste/run the answer easily. If you want to show a better way to use data.table - which your answer does, of course - why not just add those three lines after a break at the end.

Comment: @jlhoward, I see. Sure, feel free to change it. My intent was to show the answer upfront (that it's just 1 line - no join or data.frame(.) necessary, not to mention speed). I felt that the code to generate the data hindered the answer's brevity. No other reason.