# Combining dplyr::do() with dplyr::mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to achieve the following: for each subgroup of a dataset, I would like to carry out a regression, and the residuals of that regression should be saved as a new variable in the original dataframe. For instance,

```
 group_by(mtcars, gear) %>% mutate(res = residuals(lm(mpg~carb, .)))
```

indicates what I think should work, but does not (anyone care to explain why it does not work?). One way to get the residuals is to do the following:

```
 group_by(mtcars, gear) %>% do(res = residuals(lm(mpg~carb, .)))
```

which gives me a dataframe in which `dbl`-objects are saved, i.e. those contain the residuals for each group. However, it seems they do not contain the original rownames that would help me to merge them back to the original data.

So, my question is: how can I achieve what I want to do in a dplyr-kind of way?

Obviously, it can be achieved in other ways. To give you an example, the following works just fine:

```
 dat <- mtcars
 dat$res <- NA
 for(i in unique(mtcars$gear)){
   dat[dat$gear==i, "res"]  <- residuals(lm(mpg ~ disp, data=dat[dat$gear==i,]))
 }
```

However, my understanding is that `dplyr` is made for this purpose, so there should be a `dplyr`-style way?

Any hints / tips / comments are appreciated.

Remark: this question is very similar to [lm() called within mutate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24766450/lm-called-within-mutate) except that in that question, only one parameter per group is retained, which makes a `merge`-approach easy. I have an entire vector with no rownames, so that I would have to rely on the ordering of the vector to do that, and that seems troublesome to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(lazyeval)
eq <- "y ~ x"
dat <- mtcars
dat %>% 
    group_by(gear) %>% 
    mutate(res=residuals(lm(interp(eq, y = mpg, x = disp))))
```

or without `lazyeval`

```
dat %>% 
    group_by(gear) %>% 
    mutate(res=residuals(lm(deparse(substitute(mpg~disp)))))
```

Comment: Perfect! This shows me how to do it, and gives the exact same result as the `for`-loop above. So the reason why the first line in my question did not work is because `lm` does not find the variables in the data passed from group? But why not? I think I still haven't understood the technical problem that arises for `lm` here, so if you care to explain, I would appreciate that. In any case, thanks for the answer. It solves my problem perfectly!

Comment: I might be wrong. It is often problematic/ ambiguous to call functions that routinely uses SE, inside `mutate`. It is nice to see that R is smart enough to spot the ambiguity and raise an error in most cases. But sometimes, it goes unnoticed, like `mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% mutate(res = nrow(subset(., am==0)))`. Not a real answer. Just an observation from experience.

Answer (score 0):

```
#This gives you the residuals. You can then combine this with original data. 
mtcars %>%
     group_by(cyl) %>%
     do(model = lm(mpg ~ wt, data=.)) %>%
     do((function(reg_mod) {
        data.frame(reg_res = residuals(reg_mod$model))
     })(.))
```

Comment: I assume you mean I can `cbind` mtcars and the residuals from your approach? When I do this, i.e. `dat2 <- cbind(mtcars, res)`, where `res` refers to the outcome of your code above, I get a mean relative difference of 1.532817 from `all.equal(dat$res_for, dat2$reg_res)`, where `dat` is defined in my question, and `res_for` is the residual generated by the `for`-loop. Am I misinterpreting your answer?

Comment: You have to use `cbind(mtcars,res)` to get the desired output (`res` is the output from the code above.. You can verify the output (which I did) by running say, for cyl==4, `kk<-lm(mpg~wt,data=mpg[mtcars$cyl==4,])` and `cbind(mtcars[mtcars$cyl==4,],kk$residuals)`.

Comment: I am still not sure how to use your approach in a way that would resemble a straightforward `dplyr`-style solution. Do you think you could augment your answer? Maybe it helps to clarify that I know how to get the residuals. In fact, I have shown this myself in the second line of my question. I wonder how to efficiently recombine the residuals to the original dataset without the need to loop over groups myself. I have not yet understood how to do this with your approach.